# HTML load speedup

Tags: html, http, optimization, header, compression

I want to speed up loading of an HTML page.
I know I can compress the HTML, JS, and CSS, however I was thinking of taking this a step further.
Instead of having links to CSS and JS files, I would (or the server) just copy&paste their contents in the HEAD directly. That is basically to save a few TCP round trips to the web server.

What I don't know is...
Does the browser make a separate HTTP request for each JS and CSS file?

Will appreciate your input

Thanks!
-Assaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for each of the JS and CSS, there is a seperate HTTP request. However, the TCP connection can be same and could be different depending on the Keep-Alive header.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive

Have you thought that just copy pasting the JS and CSS into the head can make your site difficult to maintain. I would always keep my CSS and JS at the central location even if it adds small overhead to performance.

You might want to check compression technology provided by your web server. For instance, if you are using IIS, check out IIS compression

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/d52ff289-94d3-4085-bc4e-24eb4f312e0e.mspx

Comment: Hey, the final output pages will be different from the maintained pages. The idea I had was to make a separate site for development where everything will be nice and tidy but the production site will be all compresses and have all CSS and JS in the heads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can watch these requests in action with a header analysis tool, such as [LiveHTTP for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/).

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html is a great summary of further optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No. Generally yes, but you can stop  unwanted  JS and CSS requests  on returning visits by enabling browser caching.  Caching, however is only helpful when substantial share  of requests come  from returning users,  and also, if JS and CSS files are not changed very often.  You would need to set up caching time in response headers based on their expected volatility. This [Caching Tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) explains use of caching headers.

Another approach to avoid stale cache is to rename JS and CSS files and their references in HTML on every change.

If the same JS and CSS files are referenced in many HTML pages, than keeping them separately from the pages should be more optimal for performance.